# Transporter fleet - from node1 to node 2 then storage

Tags: anylogic

I want to modelize a forklift flows: at the beginning the forklift will pick a box in node1 then go to node2 with 20 sec of delay after that the same forklift will take the box to the storage.
I'm using transporter fleet( so only the purple blocks work in my model).

I tried put this logic: movebytransporter ( checked only the seize option without release Transporter) -> delay(20sec) -> ReleaseTransporter -> store but the forklift put the box just after the release and go otherwise the box waits for an another forklift to do the action "store". but as I explained I want the same forklift who takes the box to the node2 he will take it the storage system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYgit.png)
I tried also : seizeTransportre -> moveTo (the blue block) -> releaseTransporter -> store but the box goes to node2 by itself and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW7MQ.png)
I tried this logic too : seize -> moveTo (node2) -> Delay (20 sec) -> store -> release. And I got the box moves to node2 by itself. This might be because I used "seize Transporter (transport fleet)" instead of a "resource pool"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYl1J.png)
this logic gives me an error which is "the agent is already seized".

Comment: pls replace the long text with some screenshots, makes it much easier to understand your problem :)

Comment: @Benjamin thank you for your return. I added some screenshots